# Angular 2 | Prevent button click to clear form

Tags: angular, forms

My form has a button to add an item to the object's array.

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" #myForm="myForm" class="form-horizontal" style="direction: ltr"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Transaction ID:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9"> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="asn.TRANSACTION_ID" name="TRANSACTION_ID" placeholder="Enter password">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-11">
      <button  class="btn btn-info" (click)="AddEmptyLot($event)">Add Item</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=lot-row *ngFor="let item of asn.itemsList;let i = index">
    <div class="row lot-row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-1"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="removeLot(i)">X</button></div>
          <label class="control-label col-sm-3">ITEM ID:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.ITEM_ID" name="itemid" placeholder="ITEM ID">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-4" >Customer Part Number:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.CUST_PART_NUMBER" name="custpart" placeholder="Customer Part Number">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When clicking the add button, the functionality working as expected, but the form getting reset.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Thanks for helpers.

Comment: can you provide ts file? and what you mean by reset?

Comment: Is the page reloading?

Comment: Reset mean that all the fields are cleaned.
The page not reloading.

Comment: Ok, please provide the ts file

Comment: Provide your `component.ts` file

Answer (score -1):

If you need to retain the values that are entered in the form already, you can do

```
onSubmit(value) {  
  this.retainFormValues();
}

retainFormValues() {
  for (let name in this.myForm.controls) {
    this.myForm.controls[name] = this.myForm.get(name).value;
  }
}
```